# Combined .NET app for azure and windows, EF, SignalR Client

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, signalr, azure-webjobs

I am creating a basic decentralized .NET logger which IS logging to a relational database using entity framework. The database can be SQL Server, SQL compact, etc. The application itself is a SignalR Client and log messages are pushed from the server to the app.

The application needs no user interface or anything. It could be a windows service, console application, etc.

My challenge is to choose an application type which can run both on a windows computer as well as being deployed to azure.

I have looked into creating it as a console application and deploying it as a web job. Also price is important, the application is basic, so the cost on azure should not be high. 
What would be an ideal application type for this project?

Comment: where would this relational database be located, in azure as well? Please explain more about which parts run where.

Comment: @PeterBons If the applcation runs on azure, then the database is on azure. If the application runs on i.e windows 10 machine, then the database might be a sql server local or sql server compact on disk on same machine. It depends on the customer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a SignalR server could be hosted in IIS, but it could also be self-hosted (such as in a console application or Windows service) using the self-host library. If IIS is not available (or not install) on your windows computer, self-host would be preferable. As you said, you could create a SignalR server that's hosted in a console application, and it could be easy to deploy as a WebJob.

In order to save money, if you deploy it as a WebJob in your App Service web app, you should to choose an appropriate [App Service plan tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) based on your requirements of app capabilities and performance. If you’d like to host it in [Azure Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cloud-services/) worker role, you should use appropriate Instance size and count.

You could use [Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to estimate your expected monthly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The application is not a SignalR server, it has the client function only, with a registered callback to listen for push-log-messages. Is deploying it as a web-job a money saver? VMs are expensive on azure.

Comment: According to your description and requirement, in my opinion, deploying it as WebJob could be cost-effective. And Azure App Service is a managed platform, it is more easy to use and manage.